# Redirect the background process output to a pager `less` after finish running not to default terminal

Tags: background-process, less

By default, if you execute a background process ended with `&`, like `./test &`, the output will be printed in the current terminal.
How can I redirect the output to a pager like `less` when it finishes running other than output directly?

Comment: Are you asking how to make the `less` interface pop up when the first process completes, and not before?

Comment: I think it is. The background process finishes running, then the output will be redirected to `less`.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way: Redirect the output to a file.  When the command has finished executing, view the file in `less`.

1. `./test.sh >test.out &`
2. `less test.out`

This is under some circumstances also useful even if the command is not run in the background, for example if compiling a large project:

```
$ make >make.out 2>make.err
```

or

```
$ make >make.log 2>&1
```

Then you can, in your own time go through the output to look for errors etc. (or send it to the developer as part of a bug report), without having to scroll up and down in your terminal.

Comment: It is an option, but if the program running time is long, then you must wait  the background process to be finished, then you can check the output of it with `less` manually. But what I want it is that it will automatically redirect to `less` just like it will automatically output the result to the terminal after it finishes.

Comment: @zhenguoli The output to the terminal doesn't necessarily happen _after_ the command exits. It may appear so if the output is buffered (and doesn't fill the buffer before exiting), but that is not always the case. Output to the standard error stream is usually unbuffered, I believe, and the standard output stream can be made unbuffered too.

Comment: @zhenguoli I believe you can use `less +F` for that.

Comment: Yes, it can get the output continuously. It a good alternative. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this : `(./test | less) &`.

When it finish executing, `less` will be paused in the background. All what you have to do then is to use `fg` to show the output of `less`.

The parenthesis are not mandatory (you can remove them if you want), but they make the command looks cleaner.

Comment: It works, but what I really want is that the background process will be executed in background, then I will not wait for it to be finished executing. And if it finished running, I can check the output via less, not by the default print.

Comment: I don't get it, I tried it in my computer, and the process is executing in the backround.

Comment: In my computer, it will be executed when you execute `fg` other than executed in `(./test | less) &`, because my test program has set a program running end alarm.

Comment: You can choose another approach. You can use this `nohup ./test &`, but after the execution, you have to execute `less nohup.out` to read the output.

Comment: It will be ok, but it will need two steps to do that not just in one command which is I want to find. Thankyou anyway.

Comment: I know this might seem stupid, but you have to let the command some time before executing `fg`. Because if you execute `fg` just after executing the command, you will find that the command is still running. I tried this on my computer `(find . | less) &`, and after few seconds, I type `fg` and the output is already full in `less`.

Comment: Yes, that is.  In any case, the output can be got until it finishes running.

Comment: The pipes execute the programs in parallel, the second program doesn't wait until the first end to get all the output, the output is send progressively.